# Question about instances and Dictionary of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, instance

Hello I've built a simple packet skeleton where each packet is a class file which extends a interface but whatever that's not important just a little intro to show you how it works and what i'm attempting to do.

say it's something like this

```
public static void HandlePacket(Player player, Packet p)
{
    PacketHandler handler = null;

    if(handlers.TryGetValue(p.getId(), out handler)) {
        handler.handlePacket(player, p);  
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Unhandled packet: " + p + ".");
    }
}
```

But okay the code above is a bit unrelated to this question.. my question has to do with filling up the handlers in the most efficient way.

handlers pretty much is just

```
private static Dictionary<int, PacketHandler> handlers = new Dictionary<int, PacketHandler>();
```

Now I cannot decide which way to populate the handlers map.

First way which is ugly goes something like this.

```
PacketHandler temp;
temp = new TalkPacket();
handlers.Add(33, temp);
handlers.Add(66, temp);
handlers.Add(22, temp);
handlers.Add(11, temp);
```

the elegant way looks like this.

```
handlers.Add(33, new TalkPacket());
handlers.Add(66, new TalkPacket());
handlers.Add(22, new TalkPacket());
handlers.Add(11, new TalkPacket());
```

My question is about the references why create more objects.. when you can re-use them.

So really I'm unsure does the ugly way only make one instance of TalkPacket object or 4? like the elegant way, if there is no difference with the code above. Then I might as well go with the elegant way.

I only will be including no more then 255 packets anyways so 255 objects big deal.. but most of the packets will be shared with other opcodes which is why I keep thinking why initiate more instances when they do the same thing.

At first i was looking for a way to bind multiple int datatypes to one object and having easy access like the **TryGetValue** command.

Anyways if anyone has any good suggestions let me know. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a java question. Use Camel Case to name methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way there is only one instance of TalkPacket created and all the 4 entries in the Dictionary reference this single instance.

In the second one, there are 4 different objects of type TalkPacket.

So no, these two are not equivalent.

Comment: Wait up fiver can you help me out here say I do this. PacketHandler temp;
temp = new TalkPacket();
handlers.Add(33, temp);
handlers.Add(66, temp);
handlers.Add(22, temp);
handlers.Add(11, temp);
temp = new MovePacket();
handlers.Add(44, temp);           will 33,66,22,11 = talk and 44=move or... all change to move?

Comment: great.. just wonderful how things work the way you want them to.. I could of swore temp would of been overridden in all keys values. They must do a copy erm.. still create a new instance i guess under the hood. Which could make them all equivalent hehe.. idk.

Comment: all variable in C# are reference variables, so they just 'point' to the objects. You can have different references to the same object. So the dictionary has 4 different references to the same object each one corresponding to key=33, key=66 etc. When you add the reference is copied, not the object itself.

Comment: so how in the world will those objects ever be cleared? if I reset temp to a different object old object isn't accessible yet... since it's accessible in the dictionary it's all fine.

Comment: As you state the reference is something unreachable? the reference to the variable (temp) would just be the last object? (Move) and the (Talk) which was previously set to temp will still exist? 100% on this. I don't want it to be cleared. just want to know what i'm trying to do the will work without problems? ya? or must I do..  PacketHandler temp1, temp2; temp1 = new TalkPacket(); temp2 = new MovePacket(); handlers.Add(11, temp1); handlers.Add(22, temp1); handlers.Add(33, temp3); many possibilities I guess it's all after I set temp to Move I cannot add anymore Talk to dictionary i understand

Comment: look objects are created on the heap, references to them are on the stack. temp is a reference on the stack that points to the object on the heap. There are 4 more copies of these references, which are in the Dictionary. The references exist until they are out of scope. An object exists until is't collected by the garbage collector - this can only happen if there is no more references that point to it (i.e. it's unreachable). If you can't understand this, you should probably read it up in some intro book about C# or Java (they are the same in this sense)

Comment: I understand i just had a brain fart. But that stack idea sounds dangerous those references would get popped out eventually. But then again I believe I create these new references every time I access the dictionary? Heap sounds like a safe place (I'm just assuming things logically here). I come from Java where I get highly bloated memory usage apps opposed to C#. Figured it may operate differently.. In java I could create a ArrayList of something and null the object that's held by the ArrayList yet it will still exist in the List. All cool no need to respond.Thanks again and have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a dictionary for this:

on the dictionary where you do:

```
PacketHandler temp;
temp = new TalkPacket();
handlers.Add(33, temp);
handlers.Add(66, temp);
handlers.Add(22, temp);
handlers.Add(11, temp);
```

is the same as:

```
private static PacketHandler handler = new TalkPacket();
public static void HandlePacket(Player player, Packet p)
{
    PacketHandler handler = null;

    if(idList.Contains(p.Id)) { // no need for dictionary, just array or list of int
        handler.handlePacket(player, p);  
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Unhandled packet: " + p + ".");
    }
}
```

While the second method you proposed is the same as:

```
public static void HandlePacket(Player player, Packet p)
{
    PacketHandler handler = null;

    if(idList.Contains(p.Id)) { // no need for dictionary, just array or list of int
        handler = new TalkPacket();
        handler.HandlePacket(player, p);  
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Unhandled packet: " + p + ".");
    }
}
```

The second approach is slower.

Comment: This isn't a java question. Use Camel Case to name methods.

Comment: TalkPacket is just one of those packets.. how about like.. MovePacket(); how will handler.HandlerPacket() reflect MovePacket.. you really confused me now.